# Unable to drag and position NSWindow below dock

Tags: objective-c, macos, interface-builder, nswindow

I have a `NSWindow` that I've created in IB and then setup programmatically:

[image]
[image]

```
-(void)viewDidAppear {
    // Keep window on top
    [self.view.window setLevel:CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGMaximumWindowLevelKey)];

    // Keep rounded corners with no title bar
    [self.view.window setOpaque:NO];
    [self.view.window setStyleMask: NSTitledWindowMask | NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask];
    [self.view.window setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
    [self.view.window setTitlebarAppearsTransparent:YES];
    [self.view.window setTitleVisibility:NSWindowTitleHidden];
    [self.view.window setShowsToolbarButton:NO];
    [self.view.window standardWindowButton:NSWindowFullScreenButton].hidden = YES;
    [self.view.window standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton].hidden = YES;
    [self.view.window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton].hidden = YES;
    [self.view.window standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton].hidden = YES;
    [self.view.window makeKeyWindow];
}
```

I'd like to be able to drag and reposition this `NSWindow` below the dock. Trying to do so snaps the `NSWindow` back above the dock upon releasing it, as seen in the GIF.

[image]

How can I make it so this `NSWindow` is able to be positioned below the dock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [`-[NSWindow constrainFrameRect:toScreen:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindow/1419779-constrainframerect?language=objc) to constrain, or not constrain, however you like. To prevent your window from being constrained, just return the proposed frame rect unmodified.

Alternatively, you could use a borderless window instead of one with a title bar which you then hide. What the system is doing is moving the window so its title bar remains above the Dock's top. It wouldn't do that if it didn't have a title bar, I don't think.

Comment: Ah yes the title bar! That makes alot more sense now. Went with overriding the method. Thank you.